# Is there any api to convert city names into longitude and latitude

Tags: api, google-maps

I have city names in my database and I'd like to get those city longitude /  latitude in order to pin them in google map, my question is:

**Is there any website/package that provides such service to convert city names into longitude and latitude?**

*If yes I'd be appropriate if you can share the link.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Google’s own [Maps API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/) will do that, and many more things besides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i do use google api (well free version) but i couldn't find any doc specifically about converting city names to lon-lat

Comment: @mafortis The documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro